# How to check users permissions to view page against the pages view permission in ASP .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions

I am lost on this problem.

I have an ASP .NET/C# (Not MVC) site that uses Active Directory Membership, this portion works perfectly. I now need to setup permissions for the pages of the site and give users the proper permissions to view the pages. BUT, this is a big but too, I cannot use role manager because the AD roles are not setup properly, and I cannot use SQL role manage either becuase the senior programmers want to be able to restrict users from not just web pages, but also be able to restrict users from buttons, TxtBoxes, and more from web pages if necessary.

I know that I can put code in the Masterpage to check the users permission for every request. I also know that I will use SQL tables to hold users (username), permissions (Admin, view forms page, etc.), and userHasPermissions (Joe has Admin, Bob has view forms, etc).

Where I am lost:

I am lost on how to set the pages permissions. How do I say that 'contact' page requires admin rights, and staff directory requires only view permissions? Will I use a custom web.sitemap? Or will it go in my database? I have a lot of pages on the site, so what would be the best way to do this?

How do I capture the page request to check the required permission and then cancel it (throw an exception) if they do not have the permissions?

Correct me if I am wrong. But I will have to query the database constantly from my masterpage to check the permissions. Right?

Sorry for all the questions.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly it makes more sense to fix AD than to write a workaround. I will leave my original answer at the bottom in case you decide to fix your AD roles/Security Groups.

If you are using SQL tables to store the users and their roles just run a query that creates a dataset based on the roles you want, if the dataset returns rows you know there is a match and you can perform your logic from there (hide buttons, redirect to an access denied page, etc.)

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
 using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT <USER> FROM <User_Roles> WHERE <USER> = @User AND <ROLE> = @Role", conn))
    {
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Role", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Admin";
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         da.Fill(ds);
         if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
         {
                  //Make things available          
         }
         else
         {
                  //Make things unavailable or hidden         
         }
    }
```

RECOMMENDED ANSWER:
Fix your SGs and put this on each page to define who has permission, if they don't have permissions redirect them to an access denied page.

```
if (!(Page.User.IsInRole("Domain\\Security Group")) && !(Page.User.IsInRole("Domain\\SG2"))
                && !(Page.User.IsInRole("Domain\\SG3")) && Page.User.Identity.Name != "Domain\\USER")
            {
                Server.Transfer("~/AccessDenied.aspx");
            }
```

Then on the access denied page just grab the username and relay a message to the user

```
public void GetUserName()
{
    string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    Response.Write(userName.ToString());
}
```

ASP

```
<section>
     Access denied to <% GetUserName(); %>
</section>
```